What's the funds ferry replacement?
I read the following on https://www.piercecountywa.gov/CivicSend/ViewMessage/message/98761 about  vehicle registration fees and taxes in WA, USA:

• $8 service fee: Funds are retained by subagent, or funds ferry replacement if renewed at County Auditor/DOL

What does ferry mean here? Looking at dictionary, most meanings are about boat-related activities.  But I don't see why vehicle registration fees and taxes would help fund some boat-related activities, so I'm starting to question my English understanding.

I suspect that if you ask 10,000 native speakers, 9999 of them would shrug and say "I have no idea what that means".  They will know what the individual words mean, but as a phrase it is opaque.  The syntax would suggest that it has to refer to something that has the capacity to retain funds.

In Washington State  on the US west coast there are sections of Seattle accessible only by ferry.  But that still doesn't shed enough light on the phrase.  I think maybe the word funds is a verb there (following or but is a noun in the first part of the bullet point) and the implicit subject is the $8 fee.  The fee is retained... or it is used to pay for replacement ferries.  The punctuation could be misleading.
https://wsdot.wa.gov/travel/washington-state-ferries

I agree with @TimR. Try replacing the second occurrence of funds with pays for in the original context and see if you can’t find a way to make sense of it (by which l mean find a subject for the verb funds). In any event, the passage you quote is very poorly worded; it seems nobody took any care to review it for understandability.

Yes, a "ferry" is a boat used to transport people, vehicles, or sometimes other cargo a short distance, like across a bay.
"Ferry" as a verb can be used to mean "transport a short distance". Like you could say, "We used my brother's pickup truck to ferry our furniture to our new apartment."
But here, it appears to be referring to a literal boat. Note up a little on the same page it says that the "commercial trailer fee" pays for "ferries and various transportation projects".
It's not uncommon in the US for taxes and fees to be used to pay for something totally unrelated to the service they're charging the fee for. In this case it's not that much of a stretch. I don't know what ferries they have in this area, but it's not uncommon for ferries to transport cars across a river or bay. So to say that your vehicle registration fee goes to pay for a ferry that you might use to transport that vehicle is not a startling idea. Of course you might never use the ferry, but that's the nature of taxes. You pay for some service to benefit the "community", whether you personally use that service or not.
